# Can encrypting a virtual machine help guard against source code theft?

Tags: php, security, encryption, webserver, virtualbox

I have developed a web service running on regular LAMP web server. I need to get it to the customer to run it on their own server. I'm afraid of the possibility that the customer will steal all of the content on the web server and am looking for the right setup that I can offer.

I was thinking of VirtualBox running on the server, but is it also possible it can be hacked by mounting it as a regular data/disk? Can I perhaps encrypt the image? I need the customer to be able to restart the PC that runs VirtualBox and restart the virtual machine without me.

The biggest problem is that the server is not connected to the internet, so there's no chance I can manage the server by myself remotely. And also afaik even if you have encrypted the image, if it runs it is actually un-encrypted and the keys possibly could be dumped from RAM.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Another approach would be to use something like zend guard - http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard

Comment: A legal contract with your customer might be a good idea, and a lawyer to hand if the contract is broken

Comment: Like Mark says, this is a legal problem, not a technical problem.

Comment: combining both way above is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting the virtual disk still requires a decryption key to run the machine.  There is no way around this requirement.

What you should do is provide reasonable safe guards against copying your code.  I would say that putting it on a VM image is sufficient.  I'm not a lawyer, but it's my understanding that if there is *some* barrier to copying your code, then if someone does steal from you that you can show that they went out of their way to do so, violating your terms of service.  Again, this won't prevent anyone from stealing from you, but it does make the legal ground behind it clearer.

On another note, I have deployed VMs that I want to stay locked but without any code on them.  Instead, I use a simple Git deploy key which I can revoke at any time.  When the VM boots, it checks out my code from Git into a ram disk.  While the VM is running of course, someone could get into it and steal the code but this is difficult.  When it's not running, someone can get to the disk image and add code to let them in later, steal the deploy key, or other things.  Again, the goal here is to cause a thief to do something in order to steal from me, making the legal ground a bit stronger.